# How to save third-party libraries, transport them and launch an application with them Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, libraries, packaging

Basically, the title is the question. 
I'm looking for a possibility to save third-party libraries in the application folder and run this application with these libraries on another PC (internet on PC is not available.) Don't want to run this application as a zip archive with one entry point, just as a basic python app based on this locally installed third-party libraries. 
Any advice on tools?

Comment: Are you looking to have a single executable like file to run on the other computer, or do you specifically want to store the third party libraries on the application folder?

Comment: @adam, want to store 3'rd party libs and run an application on another PC. Two things to consider - quick changes on another PC, run without libs installation.